# How to say that I'll do something after I cool off/calm down after a stressful/anxious situation?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I'm in shock after a stressful situation and I can't do anything. I want to say that I'll do something after I calm down. What's the best way to say that? Does something like for example "out of shock" exist?

Comment: 'I'm okay now', 'I've recovered', etc

Comment: I need time to wake up (as in become conscious or aware).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A person who is under stress is said to be *wound up* and they need **time to unwind**.

A person whose life is *coming apart at the seems* or whose *life is falling apart* (has lost control) needs to **pull himself together**.

Someone faced with a sudden shock may need to **get a grip on himself**.

If the stress has continued to build, and you can't take it anymore, you may need to **let off some steam** or **decompress**. Or you might want to **come up for air**.

The simplest thing to say after experiencing something stressful or shocking is **I need to take a timeout** or simply **I need a break**.

You might tell someone that you need to do any of these things before you can move on.

Answer (score 1):

You might say you will do something after you *decompress*:

> to undergo release from pressure; especially :  relax
>
> *need a week off to decompress*

source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decompress)

Here's an article titled [12 Ways To Decompress After High Stress](https://zenhabits.net/12-ways-to-decompress-after-high-stress/).

You might also consider using the phrase *back at/to baseline*. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/baseline) defines baseline as:

> 4
>   :  a usually initial set of critical observations or data used for comparison or a control
>
> 5
>   :  a starting point

*Back to baseline* means returning to an initial state. Here is an article titled [Back to Baseline](http://www.aafp.org/afp/2013/0801/p170.pdf) describing a patient's recovery after a serious car accident.

Answer (score 1):

> I will do it after I ***settle my nerves***.

Cambridge:

> **[settle your nerves](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/settle-your-nerves)** ​
>   to make yourself feel calmer:
>   After the accident, he went for a walk to try to settle his nerves.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I might say, if I had my snappy diplomatic comeback pants on:
"That was so disturbing. Please give me a few moments (days?) to gather my thoughts and I'll be ready to address this next matter."